# Different Edit Forms for Different Groups

Tags: sharepoint

I am setting up an Inquiry list. There will be two groups of users: Requestors and Administrators. The Requestors will fill in a form with basic information and their question. The Administrators will respond to the inquiry and have additional status fields to fill in; these fields should not be visible to Requestors (essentially, two different forms). What do I need to do to allow the Requestor to see one form, while the Administrators see a different form (containing all of the fields from the Requestor form as well as Administrator-only fields) when they edit the request? I'd like to do this without having both forms show up on the "New" button.

Also note that I am prohibited from using anything other than Sharepoint's "out-of-the-box" functionality.

Thanks!
Ralph

Answer (score 0):

I would keep the same form myself, but get the Administrators fields to not display.

[Boost Solutions](http://www.boostsolutions.com/columnpermission.html) may be what you are after.

Comment: Ahh! I should have stated in my original question that I have to use Sharepoint "out-of-the-box" functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Forms Designer](http://spform.com) tool. It allows to personalize forms based on the current user membership, permissions and field values.